# Composite Index in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery, composite-index

I have a kind name 'Wdr'. My index.yaml file looks like this .

```
indexes:
-kind: Wdr
 ancestor: yes
 properties:
 -name : wdr_id
 -name : wdr_sub_id
  direction: desc
```

I am not able to run this gql query below.

```
SELECT * FROM  Wdr where wdr_id = '1098' order by wdr_sub_id desc
```

The eror i get is..

```
GQL Query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query.
```

Is the indexes define in the .yaml file is not correct? or am i doing something else wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index definition contains `ancestor: yes`, this means that your query should contain an ancestor filter.  You can either add an ancestor filter to your query or change your index definition to `ancestor: no`.

Comment: 'SELECT * from `Wdr` WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(Tan, 'f347e5bd-8204-4ff1-b7a5-ae2b65a7ac38')  ORDER BY welder_sub_id asc ' this query didnt worked too

Comment: 'SELECT * from `Wdr` WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(Tan, 'f347efbd-8204-4ff1-b7a5-aecb65a7ac38') ORDER BY wd_start_time asc'  What indexes should i add for this query?

Comment: The error message from trying to use the query should give the needed index.  I'd expect it to be `kind: Wdr
 ancestor: yes
 properties:
 -name : wdr_sub_id/wd_start_time
  direction: asc`